# How to remove liquidity by code?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to remove the liquidity previously added by the contract itself.

```
function getPoolPair() public view returns (address) {
    return IPancakeFactory( pancakeRouter.factory() ).getPair( address(this), pancakeRouter.WETH() );
}


function getPoolLiquidityInBNB() public view returns(uint256){
    return IERC20( getPoolPair() ).balanceOf( address(this) );
}

function addBalanceToLiquidity() public {
    approve( address(this), routerAddress, 1000 );
    
    pancakeRouter.addLiquidityETH{value : address(this).balance}(
        address(this),
        1000,
        0, // slippage is unavoidable
        0, // slippage is unavoidable
        address(this),
        block.timestamp + 360
    );
    
}

function removeLiquidity() public onlyOwner {
    
    uint256 poolLiquidity = getPoolLiquidityInBNB();
    
    approve( routerAddress,  getPoolPair(), poolLiquidity );
    
    pancakeRouter.removeLiquidityETH(
        address(this),
        poolLiquidity,
        0,
        0,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp + 360        
    );
}
```

The liq was created without any problem but when I try to remove it I receive the error:

`ds-math-sub-underflow`

What is the correct way to use `removeLiquidityETH` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LP token has to be approved for spending by the Router contract.
Also, check the balances of the LP tokens that you have to be exact amounts.
Another thing is to make sure if you are removing all liquidity to calculate it like this

```
uint256 public constant MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY = 10**3;
 lpTokenAmount = (Math.sqrt(tokenBInputAmount * tokenAInputAmount)) -  MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY;
```

Math.sol contract can be found here: https://github.com/dapphub/ds-math/blob/master/src/math.sol